# How to dynamically write the svg data to a file from an HTML page using JXBrowser as a background process

Tags: html, svg, jxbrowser

I am using JXBrowser and I have a valid license. I have a requirement to extract svg data from the HTML in the background using JXBrowser. HTML gets loaded from browser.loadURL(). When I print the HTML content , I see that all the data from ajax requests does not exist at all. SVG data is rendered using ajax request . I have also used the below method, but the response is same. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue ?

```
Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(browser, new Callback<Browser>() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(Browser browser) {
                browser.loadURL("");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is this issue reproducible in a regular Chrome or Chromium browser? 

In case everything works correctly in a regular Chrome browser, maybe you can make a sample which demonstrates this behavior along with the steps to reproduce the issue?

However, if you need to extract svg data from your site, I can suggest following your site's request to ajax to find out where exactly svg data is located and then extracting svg data from there directly.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your valuable time to respond ! I was able to resolve it    by creating a manual HTML file and loading it using JXBrowser.